# Can I make Emacs start in text-terminal mode (no window, like `emacs -nw`) by default?

Tags: emacs

I don't want to get sidetracked too much here, but `emacs -nw` (in my opinion) *ought* to open a graphical instance of emacs, with a popup. However, foregoing the `-nw` switch will bring up the GUI, and an embedded CLI version is implied by the **new window** switch?

Anyway, can I make this

```
emacs myfunscript.py
```

run as this

```
emacs myfunscript.py -nw
```

and keep my business on the command line, where I've grown to like it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think -nw stands for no window. Anyway you could make a shell alias, eg in bash

```
alias emacs='emacs -nw'
```

Comment: Yeah that did it. Note the space between `alias emacs` and the lack of space between `emacs=''`. At first it wasn't working, it's a sensitive command. Also, this had to go in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who compile their emacs from sources, specify `--without-x` like this:

```sh
cd <downloaded emacs source>
./configure --without-x
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

(**Optional**) While we're at it, I like to disable some semi-related features as well. This is for emacs-27.2:

```sh
./configure --without-x --with-x-toolkit=no --with-jpeg=no --with-png=no --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
make clean
make
sudo make install
```